# How to avoid or restrict MDI Child Form menu strip getting merged with MDI Parent Form menu strip?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, mdi

Is it possible to do so, and if yes how?

Screen shot of my application

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the [`AllowMerge` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.allowmerge.aspx) of the `MenuStrip` to `false`.

This will keep the `MenuStrip` on the child form, as it is, preventing it from getting merged with the MDI parent form.